# Numba returns error when using numpy inverse function

Tags: python, numpy, numba

My numba function:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
import numba

min_sample_length = 0
step = 1
subset = np.random.rand(4800)

@njit
def numba_fun():
    max_abs_t_value = -np.inf  # Maximum abs t-value of b_1 coefficient among l values
    max_t_value_index = None  # Index with maximum t-value

    for forward_window in np.arange(min_sample_length, subset.shape[0], step):

        y = subset[:forward_window]  # y{t}:y_{t+l}

        X = np.ones((y.shape[0], 2))
        X[:, 1] = np.arange(y.shape[0])


        xy = X.transpose() @ y
        xx = X.transpose() @ X

        xx_inv = np.linalg.inv(xx)

        return xx_inv# max_t_value_index

numba_fun()
```

returns an error:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function() with argument(s) of type(s): (array(float64, 2d, C))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    LoweringError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
Type of #4 arg mismatch: i1 != i32

File "..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numba\targets\linalg.py", line 800:
    def inv_impl(a):

        if F_layout:
            acpy = np.copy(a)
            ^

[1] During: lowering "$52.4 = call $52.2(a, func=$52.2, args=[Var(a, C:\Users\Mislav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numba\targets\linalg.py (792))], kws=(), vararg=None)" at C:\Users\Mislav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numba\targets\linalg.py (800)
    raised from C:\Users\Mislav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numba\six.py:669
In definition 1:
    LoweringError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
Type of #4 arg mismatch: i1 != i32

File "..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numba\targets\linalg.py", line 800:
    def inv_impl(a):

        if F_layout:
            acpy = np.copy(a)
            ^

[1] During: lowering "$52.4 = call $52.2(a, func=$52.2, args=[Var(a, C:\Users\Mislav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numba\targets\linalg.py (792))], kws=(), vararg=None)" at C:\Users\Mislav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numba\targets\linalg.py (800)
    raised from C:\Users\Mislav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numba\six.py:669
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: resolving callee type: Function()
[2] During: typing of call at c:\Users\Mislav\Documents\GitHub\trademl\trademl\modeling\sell_fear.py (3)


File "c:\Users\Mislav\Documents\GitHub\trademl\trademl\modeling\sell_fear.py", line 3:
def inv_nla_jit(A):
  return np.linalg.inv(A)
  ^

[1] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher())
[2] During: typing of call at c:\Users\Mislav\Documents\GitHub\trademl\trademl\modeling\sell_fear.py (20)

[3] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher())
[4] During: typing of call at c:\Users\Mislav\Documents\GitHub\trademl\trademl\modeling\sell_fear.py (20)


File "c:\Users\Mislav\Documents\GitHub\trademl\trademl\modeling\sell_fear.py", line 20:
def numba_fun():

        xx = X.transpose() @ X
        xx_inv = inv_nla_jit(xx)
        ^

This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.

To see Python/NumPy features supported by the latest release of Numba visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html
and
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html

For more information about typing errors and how to debug them visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-doesn-t-compile

If you think your code should work with Numba, please report the error message
and traceback, along with a minimal reproducer at:
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new

This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.

To see Python/NumPy features supported by the latest release of Numba visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html
and
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html

For more information about typing errors and how to debug them visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-doesn-t-compile

If you think your code should work with Numba, please report the error message
and traceback, along with a minimal reproducer at:
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new
```

The problem is in numpy inverse function `np.linalg.inv`, but numba documentation says it is supported numpy function for numba function.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, the code has typos that need to be fixed and undefined symbols.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Can you pease try now?

Comment: Still can't reproduce. I get `LinAlgError: Matrix is singular to machine precision.`

Comment: Are you running the latest? (it's 0.48 on Anaconda)

Comment: Yes, I am on latest

Comment: I don't get that error. My error is the same as in the post.

Comment: You can try without numba. It should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212263/discussion-between-jacques-gaudin-and-mislav).